# JPasswordField length skips the check

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I have been reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html but I have a problem. I got a simple method which checks if my `JTextField`s and my `JPasswordField`s are empty or not

So I have this one:

```
private boolean addCustomerCheckValidInfo()
{
    for(JPasswordField pf : newCustomerPasswordFields)
    {
        if (pf.getPassword().length == 0);
        {
            System.out.println("Password length " + pf.getPassword().length);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The same returns false and writes in the console:

```
Password length 3
```

As I have read on the oracle guide, passfield.getPassword().length should return the length (as it does in the system.print.out), but why does it fail at if it's equals to 0 when it's > 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (pf.getPassword().length == 0);
```

You have a typo. You added a ";" at the end of the if statement. So you really created an empty if statement. Get rid of the ";".

Comment: oh my.. thank you very much I have totally missed that one >.<